# Custom hook is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, client, cart

I am trying to get useCart() to work and it is saying it is not a function

```
"use client";

import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext();

const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART":
      // Check if the item is already in the cart
      const existingItem = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);

      if (existingItem) {
        // If the item is already in the cart, update its quantity
        return state.map((item) =>
          item.id === action.payload.id
            ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
            : item
        );
      } else {
        // If the item is not in the cart, add it with quantity 1
        return [...state, { ...action.payload, quantity: 1 }];
      }

    case "REMOVE_FROM_CART":
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cart, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, []);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCart = () => {
  const context = useContext(CartContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useCart must be used within a CartProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
```

I wrapped CartContext in layout.js in the app folder and am trying to use this function in two of my components like this.

```
const CartPage = () => {
  const { cart, dispatch } = useCart();
```

The rest of the website works but when I go to the page that needs to use useCart() I get a runtime error.
`Error: (0 , _contexts_CartContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useCart) is not a function`

Please tell me what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this in NextJs.

I wanted the cart to load on the page and i tried exporting it differently and restarting the dev server but after an hour I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You wrapped `CartContext` in your layout? Perhaps you should have wrapped your components with `CartProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a hook in your `CartPage` component, you need to add the `'use client'` directive at the top of the component, like so:

```
'use client'    
const CartPage = () => {
      const { cart, dispatch } = useCart();

// ...rest of your component
```

By default, Next.js uses Server Components, so if you need to do any operations that use state, you need to make your component a client component. More info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components)